# Load modules with Lab.js

Tags: javascript, labjs

Why  *ReferenceError: $ is not defined* ?

```
<script src="LAB.js"></script>
            <script>
     $LAB.script("jquery/jquery.js")
    </script>

     </body>

    <p><?php echo mt_rand(89,161464) ?></p>

    <script>
//Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined 

$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('reddy');
    $("p").css('color','red');
    })  
</script>
```

**But work:**

```
   window.onload=function(){
        $("p").css('color','red');
        }
```

2.**item1.js**

```
 var interface={name:'interface'};
```

**item2.js**

```
interface.hu={name:'int'};

$LAB.script("item2.js").wait();
$LAB.script("item1.js");
```

***//Uncaught ReferenceError: interface is not defined*** 
Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try :

```
$LAB.script("jquery/jquery.js").wait(function () {
   if( window.jQuery ) { //is jquery loaded
       $("p").css('color','red'); 
   }
});
```

OR

```
$LAB.script("jquery/jquery.js").wait(function () {
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $("p").css('color','red'); 
   }
});
```

See more:: [LABjs Doc](http://labjs.com/documentation.php)